# Grease pencil 2.8, how to move strokes / curves / shapes between layers within the same GP objects

Tags: grease-pencil, layers, 2d

After I draw for example a face, I want to move the hair to different layer, and the eyes to another layer, so I can move them forward or backward proportional to another elements of the drawing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In edit mode, you can select strokes and assign them to the layer of your choice with the shortcut M or by going to the Stroke menu -> "Move to layer"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround of what you asked for, but you can set the visibility of the strokes as dependent by their 3D location (Y axis) and, in edit mode, select and move all the vertices of a stroke to have them appear forward or backward.

[image]

Another workaround is to create complete copies of a layer and then delete what's unuseful and move the layer up or down for visibility.

Comment: thanks, but how to duplicate layer?

Comment: In the layer zone, under the plus and minus icons, the arrow bring you some options, like duplicate layer or merge down; but MBr's answer is the correct one!